# My Pi stopped connecting to the internet by ethernet

Tags: raspbian, ethernet, internet, pi-zero

I installed [Rasbian Jessie Lite](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) on my Raspberry Pi Zero a few hours ago.

I hooked up a multi-usb hub to the Zero. The hub has an ethernet port, where I connected my modem.

I ran `apt-get install` for:

- xorg
- mate-desktop-environment-core
- wicd (internet network manager I like)
- epiphany-browser

I could browse the internet just fine for a while, but now I can't connect. `wget http://google.com` tells me the host could not be resolved.

When I open Wicd while connected straight to my modem, I see the wired network as an option. I click "Connect," everything seems to run, but the Zero just does not connect.

Here's my output from `wicd.log` on my most recent connection attempt:

```
  2016/01/23 19:54:34 :: Sending connection attempt result failed

  2016/01/23 19:54:34 :: Putting interface down

  2016/01/23 19:54:34 :: Releasing DHCP leases...

  2016/01/23 19:54:34 :: Setting false IP...

  2016/01/23 19:54:35 :: Stopping wpa_supplicant

  2016/01/23 19:54:35 :: Flushing the routing table...

  2016/01/23 19:54:35 :: Putting interface up...

  2016/01/23 19:54:37 :: Running DHCP with hostname raspberrypi

  2016/01/23 19:54:37 :: dhcpcd[4285]: sending commands to master dhcpcd process

  2016/01/23 19:54:37 :: 

  2016/01/23 19:54:37 :: 

  2016/01/23 19:54:37 :: DHCP connection successful

  2016/01/23 19:54:38 :: Connecting thread exiting.

  2016/01/23 19:54:38 :: Sending connection attempt result success
```

Answer (score 3):

I bet your DNS resolvers aren't configured. This is a common issue in Linux.

Add nameservers in the `/etc/resolv.conf` file by adding the lines below:

```
nameserver 208.67.222.222
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

These lines add OpenDNS' nameserver (first line) and Google's DNS server (2nd line)

Alternatively, you could add the DNS servers in the GUI network manager by clicking "Properties" under the connection then setting Static DNS to the IP addresses provided.

Comment: Added those lines, rebooted, but still no luck